# How to set a default page for a folder?

Tags: content-management, redirect

[image]

I want to link a child item to this folder. So that if any visitor hit the URL pointing to this item, should automatically show the linked item/page.

What would be the best way of achieve this?

I found Aliases as an option. Would it be a good idea to use it ?

Comment: Is the item you want to link can be found anywhere in the content tree?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes !!

Answer (score 5):

Quick and clean solution:

1. Create a new template (called "Folder with default item" or whatever you prefer), inheriting from the standard Folder template
2. Add a field to your custom folder (e.g. Droptree, and set the `Source` of the field to `query:./*`)
3. Add new `httpRequestBegin` processor after `ItemResolver`. Use code (not tested - try and fix if needed):

```
public class DefaultItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (!Context.PageMode.IsNormal || Context.Item == null || Context.Item.TemplateID != DefaultItemFolderTemplateId)
        {
            return;
        }

        Item target = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Item[DefaultItemFieldIdOrName]))
        {
            target = Context.Item.Database.GetItem(Context.Item[DefaultItemFieldIdOrName]);
        }

        Context.Item = target;
    }
}
```

Code above return 404 if default item is not selected. If you want to show folder item instead, check if `target` is not null before assigning it to `Context.Item`.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a General Link field on the Folder template to allow the content editor to select which page it should redirect to by default. You would also need to create a Controller Rendering to handle the redirection and add it to the presentation details of the folder item.